# Solrj cannot connect to zookeeper from Solr Cloud Example

Tags: solr, apache-zookeeper, solrj

I started a Solrcloud by running the included example `bin/solr -e cloud`, and in that case, I managed to start up a three nodes Solr cloud and created a `gettingstarted` collection:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/collections?action=CREATE&name=gettingstarted&numShards=3&replicationFactor=2&maxShardsPerNode=2&collection.configName=gettingstarted
```

I think it comes with a embedded zookeeper running on port 9983 because I saw this output when I started the cloud:

```
...
Starting up Solr on port 7574 using command:
bin/solr start -cloud -p 7574 -s "example/cloud/node2/solr" -z localhost:9983
Waiting up to 30 seconds to see Solr running on port 7574 [/] 
...
```

However, when I tried to connect to the SolrCloud using SolrJ, it failed with the error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Cannot connect to cluster at localhost:9983/solr: cluster not found/not ready
```

[image]

Can anyone help me understand what is going on here?

Comment: For anyone wondering, the Zookeeper connection string should contain ALL zookeeper servers in your zookeeper cluster, separated by commas, SOME zookeeper configuration use a chroot or application root, this is when the ``/solr`` appears at the end of the query string.  This would be needed when you have a chroot at ``/solr`` within Zookeeper. For most configurations this can be omitted.

Comment: @BenDeMott Maybe this should be an answer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The code fails because you are trying to point the `CloudSolrServer` to a znode that does not exist.
Your zkhost is not configured with a `/solr` chroot. The configs seem to be stored at the root node.

So change the line

```
String zkHostString = "localhost:9983/solr";
```

to

```
String zkHostString = "localhost:9983";
```

and your code should work.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your zkHost. If your zkHost contains /solr , then it should be localhost:2181/solr or localhost:9983/solr; Otherwise , localhost:yourport